# Is the technique for resolving a HashMap hash collision configurable

Tags: java, hashmap, hash-collision

I was reading about hash-map resolving techniques and in one article the advantages and disadvantages were listed for separate chaining. Who decides which hash collision resolving technique is to be used? Is it purely internal, or is it configurable?

Comment: Who decides? The person creating the classes and code, of course. I'm not sure I really understand your question though.

Comment: Override `hashCode()`, return a constant value. What happens? Why?

Comment: Collision resolution algorithm is done by whoever implements the Hashmap. You can see how OpenJDK 10 does it [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/777356696811/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l624) for `setVal`, and nearby for `getNode`, the two most important methods under the hood there.

Comment: No, it isn't configurable, it's purely internal. You can only specify load factor and initial capacity.

Answer (score 3):

Simply study the interface (the public methods) of the HashMap class. There are no methods or constructors for you that alter conflict resolution behavior.

Thus the answer is: at least for the standard library class, that part is internal.

The only parameters that you can influence are capacity and the load factor, but they don't affect the conflict resolution strategy.

Comment: off topic for SO?

Comment: I consider it borderline somehow. And I do think that at least the answer is clear enough to be helpful for future readers.